# flutter release APK does not show image asset

Tags: image, flutter, assets

i have one big problem

flutter image assets are shown perfectly when i use  emulator but in released APK image are not shown.

can any person guide me

```
CircleAvatar(

            child: Image.asset('images/icon.png',width: 80,height:80,),
           backgroundColor: Colors.pink[250],radius: 90

        )
```